# jacob.dll already loadedin another classloader

Tags: java, jacob

I am implmented a webservice in java and webservice client also in java. both the webservice ane webservice client are in different project and i am created dll using jacob.

My Webservice and webservice client is on same computer.now whenever i am calling the webservice using webservice client than encounter following exception.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Native Library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jacob.dll already loaded in another classloader
root cause

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Native Library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jacob.dll already loaded in another classloader
root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jacob.dll already loaded in another classloader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jacob.dll can only be loaded once for each instance of a JVM.
If the library jacob.jar is loaded more than once, it will try to load jacob.dll more than once, too.

To avoid that, **remove** the jacob.jar from both webservices and **put** it in some place where it can be found by a classloader that both webservices share, that way jacob.jar will be loaded only once. For example, if you are using tomcat, put the jacob.jar in the /lib directory of that tomcat.

Comment: Thanks pablo.I am using glassfish server so as you told jacob.jar and jacob.dll will put into the lib folder of the glassfish??