# Native Library jacob-1.14.3-x64.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, dll, tomcat7, classloader

I have 2 java Web applications that i need to run on the windows 2008 server using tomcat as a  service.
The first one works fine but when i run the 2nd app i get the below classloader error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library `D:\ProgramFiles\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\jacob-1.14.3-x64.dll` already loaded in another classloader

I have tried the below solutions:
Copied the `.dll` file in Tomcat7.0/bin and also placed the `jacob.jar` file in the `Tomcat7.0/lib` and also set the java library path as well.

But there seems to be the something that's missing.
Appreciate any answers for the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328520/jacob-dll-already-loadedin-another-classloader